# Не найдена html страница Spring Thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring, mvc, boot

https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    
        org.springframework.boot
        spring-boot-starter-parent
        2.2.0.RELEASE
         
    
    com.example
    demo
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    demo
    Demo project for Spring Boot

```
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

[image: Структура проекта]

```
@Controller
public class Start {
@Autowired
private PlaceService repo;

@RequestMapping({"/",""})
public String greeting(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("joke","123");return 
"index";
}

@GetMapping (value = "/tables")
public String getValues(Model model)
{
    Iterable<Places> listPlaces = 
repo.listAll();
  model.addAttribute("listPlaces",listPlaces);
    return "tables";
}
```

}

Не запускается страница tables.html, но при этом работает index с заменой имени в поле th:text. Код вроде одинаковый в контроллерах.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org" >
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>table</title>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "../static/style.css" >
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
    <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Мой сайт</a>
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a href="index.html">Главная</a></li>
                <li><a href="../static/second_page.html">Вычисление прямой</a></li>
                <li><a href="tables.html">Таблица</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <td>Наименование</td>
        <td>Описание</td>
        <td>Цена</td>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:each = "place : ${listPlaces}">
        <td th:text = "*{place.name} " id="name">1</td>
        <td th:text = "*{place.location} " id="location">1</td>
        <td th:text = "*{place.info} " id="info">1</td>
    </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

В браузере пишет, что данная страница не найдена, если выставить в свойствах статичную страницу то он видит ее.

Comment: поставьте th:href="@{/table}" вместо href="tables.html"

Comment: не находит страницу 404

Comment: ошибся th:href="@{/tables}" - так пробовали?

Comment: Все получилось, спасибо, забыл отписать)